# What is the optimal way to write a flux query with a long list of tag filters?

Tags: query-optimization, influxdb, fluxlang

Say I have an influx measurement that logs a large amount of data. Each point is tagged with a unique id that identifies the source of the data and a type.

Example of entries into this measurement:

```
data,id=source1,type=temperature value=25
data,id=source1,type=battery value=80
data,id=source2,type=temperature value=22
data,id=source2,type=battery value=86
```

In addition to this I have a SQL database that has details about each source. Like location, current status, e.t.c. I want to filter data in InfluxDB based on information in this other database. So I fetch a list of ids that match my filter that I can then use for my flux query. The length of this list can be in the thousands.

My current solution for filtering based on this list is using the **contains()** function:

```
from(bucket: "my-bucket")
|> range(start: -24h, stop: now())
|> filter(fn: (r) => 
    r._measurement == "data" and 
    r.type == "temperature" and 
    contains(value: r.id, set: ["source1","source2", ...])
  )
|> ...
```

This query becomes very slow, with about 1000 ids the query takes about 30 seconds to complete. If I remove the contains filter and look at all sources at once the query takes about 1 second.

Is there a better way to do this without tagging each point with all the things that I might want to filter by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InfluxDB has a concept of pushdowns in queries. According to the documentation:

> Pushdowns are functions or function combinations that push data operations to the underlying data source rather than operating on data in memory. Start queries with pushdowns to improve query performance. Once a non-pushdown function runs, Flux pulls data into memory and runs all subsequent operations there.

In your case, your filter in the example is not pushed down to the data source but instead is most likely processed in the memory due to the processing filter inline. And contains is not the most efficient way to do it.

Try this:

```
from(bucket: "my-bucket")
|> range(start: -24h, stop: now())
|> filter(fn: (r) => r.id =~ /^(source1|source2)$/)
|> filter(fn: (r) => 
   r._measurement == "data" and 
   r.type == "temperature"))
|> ...
```

Here we use regex to filter by a list of values. It should perform better than contains. Or you can build a filter with `(r.id = "source1" or r.id = "source2")`.

More on query optimization read [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/optimize-queries/).

Comment: What a coincidence that you would answer this today as I just today found the solution of using regex being much faster. Great answer!

Comment: As a side note for future readers: Regarding performance, my experiments have shown that using regex for many filter expressions (source1, source2, etc. tested it um to source3000) is more performant than using a boolean expression.